# Get mongodb collection using Eve

Tags: mongodb, eve

I have mongod instances running on a server with a database on it.
I'm trying to set up eve as REST http API to the database, for simple respond to GET requests.

If I request http://92.51.132.110:28017/clockrefdb/test/rows by using mongod REST Interface, I get:

```
{
"offset" : 0,
"rows": [
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5745ef6494aef075d127f1d0" }, "timestamp" : { "$date" : "2016-05-25T22:31:00.035+0200" }, "frequencies" : [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ] } ,
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5747034194aef04e87df598d" }, "timestamp" : { "$date" : "2016-05-26T18:08:01.209+0200" }, "frequencies" : [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ] } ,
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5747050094aef04fe7aa7c14" }, "timestamp" : { "$date" : "2016-05-26T18:15:28.576+0200" }, "frequencies" : [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ] } ,
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5747050b94aef04ff397c81f" }, "timestamp" : { "$date" : "2016-05-26T18:15:39.779+0200" }, "frequencies" : [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ] } ,
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5747052694aef050096e5c71" }, "timestamp" : { "$date" : "2016-05-26T18:16:06.635+0200" }, "frequencies" : [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ] } ,
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "57470a1694aef0536bf1d712" }, "timestamp" : { "$date" : "2016-05-26T18:37:10.022+0200" }, "frequencies" : [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ] }
],
"total_rows" : 6 ,
"query" : {} ,
"millis" : 0
}
```

Which are the correct values from the documents in the db. 
Now if I run eve and with settings:

```
DOMAIN = { 'test':{} }                                               
MONGO_HOST = 'localhost'
MONGO_PORT = 27017
MONGO_USERNAME = 'user'
MONGO_PASSWORD = 'passw'
MONGO_DBNAME = 'clockrefdb'
RESOURCE_METHODS = ['GET']
```

And run eve with the default script:

```
python run.py
```

And `curl --header "Accept:application/json" "http://127.0.0.1:5000/test/57470a1694aef0536bf1d712"`

I get:

```
{
"_created": "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT", 
"_etag": "c020b57efefeb92a74f5d07875d9234e3aef077a", 
"_id": "57470a1694aef0536bf1d712", 
"_links": {
    "collection": {
        "href": "test", 
        "title": "test"
    }, 
    "parent": {
        "href": "/", 
        "title": "home"
    }, 
    "self": {
        "href": "test/57470a1694aef0536bf1d712", 
        "title": "Test"
    }
}, 
"_updated": "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" }
```

Two things standout: the wrong date, and the missing table. 
What do you think is provoking this incorrect reading of the db?
I guess I am missing some important  steps.
Any idea   which?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eve will only expose fields that are mapped to a known domain schema. That is done in order to allow the API maintainer total control over the exposed fieldset, as he/she might not want the whole document to be exposed.

So you have two options. You could set a proper domain schema for the endpoint, something like:

```
DOMAIN = {
  'test': {
    'schema': {
      'offset': {'type': 'integer'},
      'rows': {
        'type': 'list',
        'schema': {'type': 'dict', 'schema': ..., }
      },
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Or you could set the global `ALLOW_UNKNOWN = True`. This last setting is also available as a endpoint-level setting.

For further reference see:

- [Domain configuration](http://python-eve.org/config#domain-configuration)
- [Schema definition](http://python-eve.org/config#schema-definition)
- [General configuration](http://python-eve.org/config)